# Is genshin impact haram?

Tags: game

There is a game called genshin impact where you play a character(not me). Problem is that character's story contains worshipping(not actually worshipping) statues of archons(their concept of divine creatures), more like upgrading & cleaning statues or touching statues to gain power. And there are no religion in that game. If a character(not my character) do these things as it is their tradition will it be shirk for me? And I will never treat those statues as god instead I will treat them as powerful npc(non playable character) and I can treat them like that as the game allows me.And there are no animation of worship, character just touch the statue in cutscenes(only one cutscene) other they just stand there and do nothing and gain powers. Will it still be shirk? Please someone answer who has played genshin impact or a knowlegdeable muslim.

Comment: i guess game of thrones is haram because of the religion in the show?

Answer (score 1):

I actually had that discussion with one of my tabletop players. Feel free to disagree with me, but that's my point of view:

Please remember that you and your character are not one and the same.

When we read literature, we don't always agree with that the protagonist is doing. Not all of their actions are right, and we know it. We have our own judgment.

So, what changes if you have some amount of control over that character? Well, you may fix some of that character wrongdoings, but you probably can't fix them all. This is normal, because the protagonist have his/her own journey. You know that is true, but your character may not. Moreover, something may be wrong in our real world, but true in a fictional one. It's imaginary, after all.

So how it is a shirk for **you**, when **you** know that is right and don't agree with a fictional character?

Answer (score 0):

so far I have been playing genshin for a long time yet nothing was suspicious, until finally it turned out that after I thought again there was something suspicious after I interpreted the word in the statute or the statue "The Seven" they usually called it that, back to the statue, there things you can do with the statue, such as the words - "Worship", "blessing" - well if interpreted clearly it becomes an additional and bless / pray. indirectly it is already a shirk because we are required to do this to gain strength or increase our strength or replenish our blood by blessing to the statue and also indirectly this is brainwashing that has not been realized while we are playing. and actually the characters played are actually just silent and don't do anything to the statue, but with the words or text written on the statue, it hurts my faith and makes me worry about the shirk that has been realized to continue playing.

### So, if you are a Muslim then you worship other than your God (Allah) then it is a sin of shirk, and this sin of shirk cannot be erased and will remain a problem on the day of retribution or the day of the trial.

- 
- 

_
_
_
_
_ Addition: I have stopped after knowing this. Well, the reason I have mentioned above.
actually I'm quite happy playing the game, even if I want to go back to playing it actually by replacing the word "Blessing" in the Statue with "Magic Heal" and "Worship" to "Power Ups" well, I'm quite happy because there is nothing more distorted.

Answer (score -1):

Assalamu alaikum, I started playing this game myself and I genuinely liked it. But then I got to the part where the quest was to worship this statue, I deleted the game and I'm not going back to it. You should really avoid games that encourage you to do things like this, this game promotes it and forces you to do it to continue the game. I believe it's haram because it can really manipulate people easily to thinking this is normal, playing this game would spread its popularity and eventually kids will start playing it and thinking committing shirk is permissable. It's a shame they added these things to this game, but you should not prioritise games over deen. So please, stop playing this game for the sake of Allah.

Answer (score -3):

listen to me brother, i am living in makkah and have been my entire life.
all i can tell you is that as long as it does not change your faith or beleifs then you dont have to question everything. allah is merciful and you dont have to stop playing games just for these things. islam is lenient and u shouldnt worry. dont question everything and may allah be with you

Comment: Living in Makkah does not make you a mufti yazn!